# How to split cells at the occurence of particular string

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a long ipynb file that has several occurrences of `# %%` at the beginning of lines. (this was originally a py file created in Spyder).

Is there a fast way of splitting cells at every one of these occurrences without having to manually split?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. I only asked this question once.